# nginx using custom port

Tags: nginx, port

I have installed LEMP on Ubuntu. I am using a port 4738 as an nginx listener. Everything works fine. I can access the page as 123.123.123.123:4738.

I do want to get rid of port in the url. How to do it? I have read many answers on SO and tried but didn't work for me. Following is an example:

```
port_in_redirect off;     
location / {
    proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123:4738;
    }
```

and

```
proxy_redirect http://123.123.123.123 http://123.123.123.123:4738;
port_in_redirect off;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the default port for the protocol, you have to have the port in the URL.  You have to listen on port 80 if you expect to not have the port in your HTTP URL.

Configure your server to listen on port 80.

Comment: So there is no way to do it? If you search on Google "get rid of port in url" you will get so many answers/results. How these people are doing it and saying it worked for them? For example, https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/12/19/get-rid-of-locahostport-with-nginx-reverse-proxies/ OR http://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-a-http-request-to-another-port This is slightly different what I want to do. But it gives a hint that it would be possible.

Comment: @Vik Did you read my answer?  Do you think I will give you a different answer here in the comments?  Read up on how a URL is parsed and understand the parts of it, and you will see for yourself that what you're looking for can't be done.  If you don't use the default port, you have to specify the port.  It's that simple.  There is no magic.  There is no hackery.  it's very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Brad for a prompt reply! Is there a way to hide port from the client? People are using ports to ddos my server. I am just trying to make their work bit harder only.

Comment: @Vik No, you can't hide the port... how would anyone be able to connect to you?  You should really take time to understand how all this works before doing anything else.  I doubt you're actually getting DDoSed, and if you are, your plan for mitigating that isn't going to do anything.